# Category Specific Layered Navigation Changes (Disabling Attribute Filters)

Tags: layered-navigation

I'm trying to disable a particular attribute filter in layered navigation for a specific category. The attribute filter I wish to disable is the manufacturer in this instance.

I'm trying the following in the 'Custom Design Layout' for the category in question:-

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>manufacturer_filter</alias></action>
</block>
```

This is half working, it hides the manufacturer filter in the layered navigation, but it also hides everything else below this in `catalog.leftnav`.

Any idea how the above needs modifying to prevent that from happening?

To explain what I mean, here are screenshots.

**Before the XML update**

[image]

**After the XML update**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this, what do you mean, by "but it also hides everything else below this in catalog.leftnav."

Comment: Everything else in the left hand sidebar below `<alias>manufacturer_filter</alias>` disappears from the page.

Comment: all other filter!?

Comment: No.... EVERYTHING - I don't know how else to explain it but absolutely everything below the particular filter disappears from the sidebar (everything above it stays, everything below it vanishes). It's like a syntax error or something and the element stops loading but there is nothing in the logs.

Comment: I can provide before/after screenshot if necessary.

Comment: Screenshots added so you can see before and after the XML update.

Comment: is there anything on the pager after this? Looks like an exception ;)

Comment: Some time ago now but yes I believe this was an exception of some sort and it was rectified. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this if you rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::getFilterableAttributes` method.
For a specific category you can add a new filter.

Something like this (not tested)

```
public function getFilterableAttributes()
{
    $setIds = $this->_getSetIds();
    if (!$setIds) {
        return array();
    }
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
    $collection
        ->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
        ->setAttributeSetFilter($setIds)
        ->addStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
    if ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId() == 7) {
         //if in that specific category...You can even make this a category setting or a config setting so you won't hard code it.  
         $collection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('neq'=>'manufacturer'));
    }

    $collection = $this->_prepareAttributeCollection($collection);
    $collection->load();

    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Can't actually recall if we used this in the end but this looks a good way to define the available filters  so accepting as the answer :)